# Pandas Single Timestamp with index of offsets

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, datetimeoffset

This may be a straightforward answer, but I'm not seeing it in the Pandas v0.17.1 documentation.

I have a set of data that includes a start time in the header and then for each row of data there are offsets in milliseconds.

```
   Time  Input A
0     0   3.3337
1   500   3.3096
2  1001   3.3044
3  1501   3.3630
4  2004   3.2822
5  2504   3.3335
```

I would like to replace the 'Time' offset column with actual times.

Here is what I take from the data file (.xls):

```
>>> pd.to_datetime('Tue Mar 08 11:20:40 EST 2016')
Timestamp('2016-03-08 11:20:40')
```

I did try to use the following:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], unit='ms')
0       1970-01-01 00:00:00.000
1       1970-01-01 00:00:00.500
2       1970-01-01 00:00:01.001
3       1970-01-01 00:00:01.501
4       1970-01-01 00:00:02.004
```

But of course, the start date is wrong. I didn't see anywhere that let me choose the starting datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) `pd.offsets.Milli` and datetime `d`:

```
print df
   Time  Input A
0     0   3.3337
1   500   3.3096
2  1001   3.3044
3  1501   3.3630
4  2004   3.2822
5  2504   3.3335

d = pd.to_datetime('Tue Mar 08 11:20:40 EST 2016')
print d
2016-03-08 11:20:40

print df['Time'].apply(lambda x: pd.offsets.Milli(x) + d )
0   2016-03-08 11:20:40.000
1   2016-03-08 11:20:40.500
2   2016-03-08 11:20:41.001
3   2016-03-08 11:20:41.501
4   2016-03-08 11:20:42.004
5   2016-03-08 11:20:42.504
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Perfect! I should have started learning pandas a long time ago. Thanks.